# Getting as exception As NoSuchElement Exception

Tags: jsf

I'm  using JSF SelectOneMenu component. There are three such components in my page. The first one the selection on Country, upon onchange I'm displaying State list if the selected country is having, After that, there is another DropDown for changing the Address Type. When there is a country having a state, and upon selection of State and when I change the address type, I'm gettting the Exception, NoSuchElementException(Not every time).Please help me out for this issue. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that **exactly the same** list of select items is been preserved during the *apply request values* and *validations* phase of the subsequent request.